# Why converting output from beautiful soup to text gives me an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get a list so I can break output into 3 columns. 
So to convert it to list I simply `.text` . But it gives me an error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

lis=[]
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.get('https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=', headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
containers  = soup.findAll('li', attrs = {'class':'list-item'}) # gives container with all we need
smt = soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class':'list-meta'})
for s in smt:
    for li in s.findAll('li')[1]:
        print(li.text)
```

**Error:**

```
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If i just `print(li)`:

[image]

What exactly causes this error? `Span` tag?

I just need 3 columns:

```
Column1: Regular - Full time  
Column2: $63,606.40 - $70,137.60 
Column3: Regular - Full time
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback ? Part of it is cut off.

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: use `print( li )` to see what you get. It seems it is object which doesn't have `text`.

Comment: why do you use `[1]` with `for` loop? it can get different object then you expect. Better use `li = s.findAll('li')[1]` or directly `print( s.findAll('li')[1].text )`

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. ... One of those must not have any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select to get `Tag` elements with `text` method.

```
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=',
    headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
smt = soup.select("li.list-item")
for s in smt:
    print("---------------")
    for p in s.select("li"):
        print(' '.join(p.text.strip().split()))
```

Output:

```
---------------
County of San Diego, CA
Regular - Full time - $63,606.40 - $70,137.60 Annually
Category: Building Maintenance
Department: Facilities Management
---------------
County of San Diego, CA
Regular - Full time - $125,000.00 - $135,000.00 Annually
Category: Airports
Department: DPW-Airport Enterprise Fund
---------------
```

Comment: Awesome!   Thank you!